# Storyboard differs from Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i made a screen that looks like this

[image: Storyboard]

However, when i run the simulator it looks like this

[image: Simulator]

As you can see, some of the components get all clustered up top

**Others components are not showing because they're set to be hidden, so thats not a problem and they show in the right position**

I've tried using the autoresize feature to help me, it kinda does, because when i preview that screen with multiple sizes, like iphone 5.3 inches, iphone x.x inches, it scales properly. And i can't use autolayout, because thats a old project, if i set autolayout on, all the others screen become all messed up.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you share the code for the view at mdibrahimhassan@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set positions and sizes of the elements programatically. It's one of the best option available. With respect to view or device bounds set all the elements positions and sizes. Even though it requires lot's of efforts, it is the best way you can achieve other than using autolayouts.

Comment: How would i do it? Is there any tutorial so i can base off? And, will i need to program every size of the view to every existing size of iphones? Thank you for your reply

Comment: There are no specific tutorials will be available for this purpose. Just for reference purpose, see this: https://medium.com/@austinlouden/your-first-ios-app-100-programmatically-ca333d14a64c#.gjgk2n3t9

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help! I solved it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give constraints to any components. if you won't give constraints then your components always differ from device to device.
I shared a auto-layout tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2), so that you can make better UI and it runs properly in every device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Use AutoLayout" checkbox in the file inspector in Interface Builder. It's on by default, and will cause the system to create constraints on your views that override their frames.

The way your views are getting moved around strongly suggests to me that that that checkbox is checked for your storyboard.

Once you have auto-layout turned off there is a lot you can do with "strut and sprint" resizing masks to get your views to adjust their sizes and positions based on screen-size. It's more than I can explain in a single forum post however.